# Jest SpyOn choose the correct overload

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, sequelize.js

I do have a class that has 2 overloaded methods.

```
  public static create<M extends Model>(
    this: ModelStatic<M>,
    values?: M['_creationAttributes'],
    options?: CreateOptions<M['_attributes']>
  ): Promise<M>;
  public static create<M extends Model>(
    this: ModelStatic<M>,
    values: M['_creationAttributes'],
    options: CreateOptions<M['_attributes']> & { returning: false }
  ): Promise<void>;
```

in my unit test, I'm trying to use `jest.spyOn` to mock the first method however jest sees only the one that returns `Promise<void>`.

```
const mockInsightCreate = jest.spyOn(Insight, "create");
mockInsightCreate.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve()); // here I need to return an object of type - Insight
```

Is there a way to instruct `spyOn` to pickup the first method that returns `Promise<M>` ?

```
import {
    Model,
} from "sequelize-typescript";

... 

export default class Insight extends Model<Insight> {
```

Answer (score 11):

I know this question is old, but bellow is my answer for anyone facing the same issue who might stumble across it.

There is currently no way of instructing which overload signature `spyOn` should use. One solution would be to cast the value to whatever `spyOn` expects.

```js
mySpy.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(myObj) as unknown as void);
mySpy.mockResolveValue(myObj as unknown as void);
```

However, I personally prefer avoiding coercing the typing system if possible. Another workaround that does not require any typing judo is to mock the entire method implementation.

```js
mySpy.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(myObj));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `mockImplementation` is no longer a viable work around as it also chooses its own overload to adhere to.

Answer (score 0):

Since it doesn't seem that you can choose which overload to mock, it may be possible in your case to use the spread operator to mock any function with that name. I managed to do this with `connectToNet` in the `node-ipc` lib which has a few overloads. In my case, I wanted to execute the callback function.

```js
import NodeIPC from "node-ipc";

const connectToNet = jest.spyOn(NodeIPC, "connectToNet");

connectToNet.mockImplementation((...args) => {
  // I don't normally like using `any`, so suggestions are welcome.
  const callback = (args as any)[3];
  if (callback) {
    callback();
  }
});
```

These are the overload definitions:

```
connectToNet(id: string, callback?: () => void): void;
connectToNet(id: string, hostOrPort: number | string, callback?: () => void): void;
connectToNet(id: string, host?: string, port?: number, callback?: () => void): void;
```

I was able to mock the last one. I didn't test if the same `spyOn` also mocked the other 2 overloads.